# How to re-add background color to this input with a background image?

Tags: html, css, input, background-image

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/IFvEx

I have a basic input with a background image inside. However once added the background image, I lost the white background color for the input.

[image]

```
body {
    background: #333;
}

input {
    padding: 0 40px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    background: white;
}

#login-email{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    background: url('http://leongaban.com/_codepen/ico_email_input.png') no-repeat left center;
    //background: white;
}
```

When I uncomment the `background: white;` line, I lose the background image. `background-image` also did not work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `background-color` as opposed to just `background`.

The reason this was occurring, was because the image was added via the `background` property, and was being overwritten by the color. By being more specific and adding in `background-color`, it will not overwrite the image.

[**Updated Codepen here - it works.**](http://codepen.io/JoshC/pen/tCDnf)

**Updated CSS**

```
#login-email{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    background: url('http://leongaban.com/_codepen/ico_email_input.png') no-repeat left center;
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
}
```

As mentioned in the comment below, you can also use the shorthand propety for the background:

```
background: white url('http://leongaban.com/_codepen/ico_email_input.png') no-repeat left center;
```

Comment: Also `background: white url('http://leongaban.com/_codepen/ico_email_input.png') no-repeat left center;`

Comment: @MarcoRivadeneyra Yep! That works too, it's a good shorthand property.